# I Can Stand, But I Don't Have Legs

Tags: riddle, word

> I can stand, but I don't have legs 
>   I can eat without a mouth,
>   I can smell without a nose
>   I can see without eyes
>   But I can't do what I'm not allowed to
>   What am I?

Hint:

> There are no more of me now.

Hint 2:

> The answer is five letters long.

Hint 3:

> I can speak, without a mouth.

Hint 4:

> They can use things, but don't have anything.

Comment: This riddle has been lingering around in my head for a while now so I thought I would post it.

Comment: Is that an Aeroplane ..!!

Comment: @Subhash_Reddy Airplanes have noses.

Comment: I have a couple of answers -- train, water -- but the first hint blocks them.

Comment: @Duck.. it is no more means , is it got extincted ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan No, it means it doesn't exist and it is not allowed anymore.

Comment: After seeing the intended answer, I think this is a rather poorly conceived riddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm gonna say

> SLAVE

Reasoning:

> He can see, smell, but his eyes, nose and so on don't belong to him.
> Can't do what his master won't let him. 
> 5 letters. There are no more. Can use things but can't have them.

Comment: Nice job! This answer is correct!

Comment: Nicely done :)⁠

Comment: (@Duck) If my employer provides me with a company issued and owned laptop and cellphone and badge, and these items are in my possession, I most certainly **have** them even if I don’t own them. Without even reaching the question of ownership here (which is frankly distasteful), it seems the various assertions of not having legs, or being without eyes or mouth etc., are demonstrably false if this is the intended answer.

Comment: ^ I agree with Rubio, also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_the_21st_century) still exists in many, many forms!

Comment: I'm also in agreement with @Rubio. I'm not a fan of the unsavory implications of this being the correct answer, not to mention the accuracy of the clues.

Comment: I think there still are modern-day slaves in some parts of the world.

Comment: Good job on figuring out the intended answer! I'm afraid I'll need to reverse my upvote for the question now though.

Comment: Bit of a stretch - my shoes have laces rot13(rira gubhtu gurl ner bjarq ol zr...)

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> [ENIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) (first general-purpose computer)?

I can stand, but I don't have legs

> It was a large computer consisted of multiple boxes which literally stood on the floor (ENIAC occupied a large hall) without having any legs.

I can eat without a mouth,

> Card reader "ate" the punch cards to read information.

I can smell without a nose

> Tube burnouts etc. was common upon operation, so I believe it actually smelt of something.

I can see without eyes

> Again, card reader "saw" the information punched on the cards.

But I can't do what I'm not allowed to

> Of course, like every computer, ENIAC performed only the commands which have been ordered.

Hint 1

> ENIAC is now disassembled, so it's no more of it now.

Hint 2

> Obviously, "ENIAC" is 5 letters long.

Hint 3

> Card punch for outputting information allowed it to "speak".

Comment: The intended answer is pretty close to this, but it is a living thing. +1 :)

Comment: This is a whole lot acceptable than the accepted answer +1

Answer (score 6):

Now, let's see..

*I can stand, but I don't have legs*

> Flowers stand up from the ground

*I can eat without a mouth,*

> Plants extract nutrients from the ground

*I can smell without a nose*

> Flowers often smell quite pleasant

*I can see without eyes*

> Plants use light to effect photosynthesis, this could count as seeing without eyes

*But I can't do what I'm not allowed to*

> Plants have no brain, and thus no memory in the first place, so..

*What am I?*

> Are you a [Forget-me-not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosotis)?

Comment: Sorry, but not correct. The "But I can't do what I'm not allowed to" line is really important. +1 :)

Comment: @Duck I thought that was the part of my answer that fits particularly well, but ok :-)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure this is the right answer but it seems to fit most clues

> Sponges (barely considered animals)
>  They reside in the oceans and usually stuck to the floor
>  They have no legs-- but they appear to stand structurally speaking
>  Thay do not have mouth but can eat bacteria (see Wikipedia)
>  All sponges smell! Stink also. Yet no nose
>  Some sponges-- according to 42evolution.org -- called Glass sponges,
>  have the ability to process light. No eyes.
>  http://www.42evolution.org/can-sponges-see/
>  And finally per Wikipedia, sponges are defined as sessile metazoans or
>  multi celled immobile animals. They are not supposed to be mobile and
>  they are generally not.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not correct. Great answer though so +1  :)

Comment: @VassilisParassidis 5 letters

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> Earth

I can stand, but I don't have legs

> Earth *stands* out from the planets because of its high water content. [Reference](https://www.space.com/35526-solar-system-formation.html)

I can eat without a mouth,

> The Earth have known to swallow many. They need no mouth to devour.

I can smell without a nose

> Different parts of the Earth can *smell* pleasant or bad.

I can see without eyes

> The Earth *sees* it way around its orbit without the need for eyes.

But I can't do what I'm not allowed to
What am I?

> It is not allowed to deviate from its orbit around the Sun.

Hint 1

> There can be only one Earth; *no more*

Hint 2

> Earth is *five letters long*

Hint 3

> The Earth can *speak* through nature, in the form of winds, waves, and eruptions.

Comment: Hint one means that it does not exist anymore, not that there is only one. :) +1

Answer (score 2):

I think it’s a

> [Biologically engineered organism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_biology)

I can stand, but I don't have legs 
I can eat without a mouth,
I can smell without a nose
I can see without eyes

> Biologists can actively engineer for these traits, in fact, most engineered organisms are very simple.

But I can't do what I'm not allowed to

> Bio-engineering is restricted by a number of ethical and moral questions, due to which many conditions are placed on the functioning of such organisms.

Hint:

> There are no more of me now.
>  Your production has been stopped due to aforementioned concerns.

Comment: This doesn't abide by Hint 2

Comment: @hexomino I know, I’m just suggesting a class of organisms, it could be any one of them.